# Storage limit in windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there a limit windows server 2008 to how big your storage pool/partition size can be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using MBT the limits are (I understand) the same as Windows 2003 (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773268%28WS.10%29.aspx) for details):

- Maximum simple partition: 2TiB
- Maximum non-simple volume (i.e. single NTFS volume across multiple partitions/disks): 2<sup>32</sup>−1 clusters. So with 512 byte clusters that is ~16TiB, but could be significantly larger (e.g. 64KiB clusters gives ~256TiB).

With [GUID Partition Table](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/storage/GPT_FAQ.mspx) (GPT), the limits are 2<sup>64</sup> clusters (in theory), but it is not clear if there are any practical limits significantly below this for the volume size in general. A single parition GPT volumes is limited to 18EiB (i.e. 18×1024×1024TiB). Individual files are limited to 2<sup>44</sup> bytes by implementation limits from the NTFS format limit of 2<sup>64</sup>.

Comment: +1 Short answer to the question: no (using GPT) ^^

Answer (score 2):

The maximum NTFS volume size is ~16 TB. Just saying!

Comment: That's close to effective right?  Anyone who's tried to manage anything that large, and more specifically migrate something that large, will agree that may as well be 1 PB.

Comment: Hypothetical it could reach 16 exbibyte (16 x 1024PB). Unfortunately I cant prove it :(

Comment: -1: Not true with GPT disks.

Comment: +1 to compensate for Richard contradicting what xe xyrself wrote above, which is that [that Microsoft's NTFS implementation uses 32 bits for cluster numbers](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/os2-disc-and-volume-size-limits.html#FilesystemLimits) which is irrespective of disc partitioning scheme, and downvoting this based upon an erroneous self-contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If the volume is MBT then 2 TB is the limit.  Otherwise it's effectively unlimited.

Comment: -1: Only true for a specifically limited case (single simple partition with 512 byte clusters).